# JPA EntityManager отказывается работать после рестарта базы данных

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Я использую **JPA EntityManager** в **Spring Boot Application**.

Я запускаю базу данных и свое приложение. Во время его работы я выключаю и снова запускаю базу данных. После этого приложение ведет себя так, будто база до сих пор лежит.

Приложение снова начинает работать корректно после рестарта.

Как это вообще устроено и как это пофиксить?

Comment: Естественно. Соединение с базой данных происходит при запуске приложения. Если Вы остановите базу, а потом снова ее запустите, то соединение не будет восстановлено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете прикрутить к вашему приложению пул коннектов(например HikariCP или C3p0), и получать соединение из пула, а в пуле настроить проверку соединений. ConnectionPool будет следить за подключениями и переподключаться, когда соединение с БД вновь появится.

Comment: Спасибо. На самом деле был настроен пул common-dbcp, поменял на c3p0 и проблема пропала

Comment: Может в common-dbcp просто валидация коннектов не была настроена?

Comment: Настройки были минимальные -  количество при старте, максимальное количество, максимальное время ожидания. Возможно значения по умолчанию у них с c3p0 разные

Comment: Ну так-то да. Это же два разных CP.

Comment: Нужно было просто поменять версию commons-dbcp